# React strict mode not updating model

Tags: reactjs

I've got an app here rendering in strict mode and non-strict mode.  In non-strict mode it works fine, the model is being updated in the onChange however in strict mode this does not work. Any ideas, why and how to fix this?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qvubmx

Thanks.

Comment: Strict mode is used to debug. Read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html).

Comment: Thanks, yes I know that and also that I can get it working by just removing strict mode however what is the actual issue with this code that it does not work in strict mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, worked it out.

```
this.setState(prevState => {
     const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map((todo) => {
     if (todo.id === t.id) {
       todo.completed = !todo.completed;
     }
     return todo;
});
```

*todo.completed = !todo.completed* is actually updating prevState directly and strict-mode does not like this.

This is the correct way to do this.

```
return {
 ...todo,
 completed: !todo.completed
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3xywfc